# Overlaying one common fragment helping Other Tab Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

Here i Have a One MainActivity with four fragments and all Fragments are Just Swipe+tab view types.Each is containing listview.
Problem is that i want to load one Extra Fragment which should be common to all list view item and when i Apply onClickListener to any listItem,it should be popup like dialog and provide an information with all background fragments should working and appear with transparent background to that one common DialogFragment ...Its Kind of providing more Information to user by opening list item on that **DialogFragment**.

i applyed that Dialog fragment into one onItemClickListenet like

```
Class X extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             .......
             .......
             .......
             .......
             .......
             listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    OtherDilogFragment frag=new OtherDialogFragment(Obj);
                    frag.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
                }
             });
            }
          }
```

Please Help....How could i implement that another overlaying+transperent DilogFragment so that i can use it on each Fragment of all of the tabs...????

Answer (score 0):

Use setTargetFragment Method inside your fragment.

```
 void displayFullTweet(Object Object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FullView frag=FullView.setFullTweet(Object);
        setTargetFragment(frag, 1);
    }
```